Mann-Whitney-U and Kruskal-Wallis give different results, two categorical data
I've read the KW test is typically used for nonparametric data with 3+ categories and large sample sizes, but it can be used for 2 category data as well. As in, the formula will still work and produce an output. But it is recommended to use Mann-Whitney-U via the wilcox.test function when you have 2 categories.
In my case I have a dataset with large sample sizes for four different species (sample sizes are 400, 600, 2100, and 2300). I want to know if the abundance of these species (testing each one individually) differs among seasons, spring and summer time periods.
I was also testing this data for abundance across city levels (3 levels) and years (3 years), and used K-W testing for this.
But I decided to use wilcox.test for seasons becasue it is 2 a level category. I ran both anyways and they produce different results.
> kruskal.test(Abundance ~ Season, data=summary)

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  Abundance by Season
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 3.8571, df = 1, p-value = 0.04953

> wilcox.test(Abundance ~ Season, data = summary, correct=TRUE)

    Wilcoxon rank sum exact test

data:  Abundance by Season
W = 0, p-value = 0.1
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

So with KW it is significant (marginally), but with MW it is not significant. I'm just wondering if I should keep with KW only because my sample sizes could be considered large (although I am not sure what the cut off would be for what is considered "large" sample sizes - Google tells me it should just be more than 5!)

(1) when adjusting for multiple testing, the test decision will be identical (non-significant). (2) Ties might be one reason to give different results.

In addition to Michael M's comment, you should check what happens when you use correct=F with the wilcox.test function. You may be interested in this other thread too: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34023/which-result-to-choose-when-kruskal-wallis-and-mann-whitney-seem-to-return-contr . Note that you may also need something else than a MU or KW test, given the data you have (see EdM's comment below).

Doing separate tests on Season, Urbanization and Years is probably not what you want to do anyway, and might be hiding some important aspects of the underlying biology. You could consider a proportional odds multiple regression model or a generalized linear model better suited to abundance data; for count data, a negative binomial model can be a good choice. Those approaches allow you to evaluate all of the predictors together, in a single model.

There is a bug in either the R implementation you are using, or how you are invoking the functions. MWU and KW, when using exactly 2 groups should give you nearly identical results, with only negligible differences: .1 and .05 are way too different (regardless of the cutoff, or if you even use one).

The test statistic for the two-tailed Mann–Whitney test is equivalent to that for the two-sample Kruskal–Wallis test; but to calculate p-values you're comparing its observed value with its exact distribution for the former & with a large-sample approximation to its distribution for the latter.† Your results imply only three observations of abundance for each season,‡ so the approximation isn't all that close. (You are perhaps confusing abundance values with the relevant sample size for these tests when you write of 'large sample sizes'.) Note also that the observed value of the M–W U statistic is zero: all observations of abundance for one season are higher than all observations for the other, & a p-value of $\frac{1}{10}$ is the lowest you could have got.
So the answer to the question you asked is that you ought to use the exact test provided by wilcox.test. But it's not terribly clear what  data you've collected, & how; or what you're trying to find out from them—probably something along the lines of what @EdM suggested would be more useful.

† R's wilcox.test function uses the exact distribution by default when no observations are tied & there are fewer than 50 observations in each sample. You can force it to use the normal approximation with continuity correction by setting exact = FALSE, & without continuity correction by also setting correct = FALSE. This last will give the same p-value as kruskal.test gave you. Ties may be handled differently too—as @MichaelM pointed out—but there are no ties in your data, else wilcox.test could not have carried out an exact test.

‡ Considering the M–W test, $W=0$ means either the lowest $n_1$th observations of abundance are in Spring or the lowest $n_2$th observations are in Summer. That's $2$ ways of apportioning all observations between the seasons—out of $20$ possible ways if the p-value is to come to $\frac{1}{10}$. So either $n_1=n_2=3$ or $n_1=1, n_2=19$ or $n_1=19, n_2=1$. The function to standarize $W$ by its mean & standard deviation under the null is
$$
Z(W,n_1,n_2) = \frac{W-\frac{1}{2}\cdot(n_1 n_2)}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{12}\cdot n_1 n_2(n_1+n_2+1)}}
$$
As $Z^2$ gives the chi-squared test statistic for the K–W test, & as
$$
\begin{align}
Z(0,3,3)^2 &=\frac{27}{7} \approx 3.8571 \\
Z(0,1,19)^2 = Z(0,19,1)^2 &= \frac{19}{7} \approx 2.7143
\end{align}
$$
the only possibility is $n_1=n_2=3$.
